# How to repeat a function call in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        function loop(){
            $('#picOne').fadeIn(0).fadeOut(8000);
            $('#picTwo').delay(2000).fadeIn(6000).fadeOut(5000);
            $('#picTree').delay(10000).fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(16000);
            $('#picFour').delay(12000).fadeIn(16000).fadeOut(5000);
        }
        loop();
    });
</script>
```

But when the last pic fades out, the code doesn't repeat. What is the problem?

Comment: I think this kind of question has been answered million times

Comment: Use the `callback` function parameter. At the moment you're only calling `loop()` once.

Comment: The problem is that you are not telling it to repeat.

Comment: @roasted but still the two first answers are bad. Maybe somebody should write the correct answer ? Rory ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=loop+animation+jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you want to duration of the animation being the same for each element:

```
var $elements = $('#picOne, #picTwo, #picTree, #picFour');

function anim_loop(index) {
    // Get the element with that index and do the animation
    $elements.eq(index).fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000, function() { 
        // Kind of recursive call, increasing the index and keeping in the
        // the range of valid indexes
        anim_loop((index + 1) % $elements.length);
    });
}

anim_loop(0); // start with the first element
```

I don't know exactly how the animation should be, but I hope it makes the concept clear.

**Update:** To simultaneously fade out and in an image after a certain time period, use `setTimeout` and call `fadeOut` and `anim_loop` in the callback:

```
$elements.eq(index).fadeIn(1000, function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $self.fadeOut(1000);
        anim_loop((index + 1) % $elements.length);
    }, 3000);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/yHxe7/1/)

Comment: +1 that's the only way you can manage it without having to compute yourself the loop duration each time you change the delays.

Comment: @user1492776: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/yHxe7/. You probably have to adjust it for your code. Since you did not provide more information about your problem, this is really all I can help you with.

Comment: ok its working, but its doesnt do the animation that i want it to. i meant that when pic1 starting the fadeout, pic2 starting the fadein(at the same time). hoe can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

setInterval only except function try this

```
function loop(){
        $('#picOne').fadeIn(0).fadeOut(8000);
        $('#picTwo').delay(2000).fadeIn(6000).fadeOut(5000);
        $('#picTree').delay(10000).fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(16000);
        $('#picFour').delay(12000).fadeIn(16000).fadeOut(5000);
}
setInterval(loop, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no problem couse your function is called only once.

If you want to looped them you can use `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`

```
setInterval(function(){loop()}, 16000);

function loop(){
     $('#picOne').fadeIn(0).fadeOut(8000);
     $('#picTwo').delay(2000).fadeIn(6000).fadeOut(5000);
     $('#picTree').delay(10000).fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(16000);
     $('#picFour').delay(12000).fadeIn(16000).fadeOut(5000);

}
```

or

```
function loop(){
     $('#picOne').fadeIn(0).fadeOut(8000);
     $('#picTwo').delay(2000).fadeIn(6000).fadeOut(5000);
     $('#picTree').delay(10000).fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(16000);
     $('#picFour').delay(12000).fadeIn(16000).fadeOut(5000);
 setTimeout(function(){loop()}, 16000);
}
```

In both cases function will be called every `16 seconds = 16000 miliseconds`.

Comment: The animations are way longer than 1 second... this will create a mess ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to say that this function does work well, and whomever did it, did a great job. I edited the demo and it works well with pictures.

```
<div id="picOne">
 <img id="picOne" src="http://www.phphq.net/demos/phAlbum/album/Windows%20Wallpapers/Missing/Waterfall.jpg"/></div>
<div id="picTwo">
<img id="picTwo" src="http://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/colorful-background-21.jpg"/></div>
<div id="picTree">
 <img id="picTree" src="http://www.phphq.net/demos/phAlbum/album/Windows%20Wallpapers/Missing/Waterfall.jpg"/></div>
  <div id="picFour">
<img id="picFour" src="http://www.photoinpixel.com/mypicture/amazing-background-wallpapers.jpg"/></div>
```

Function

```
var $elements = $('#picOne, #picTwo, #picTree, #picFour');

function anim_loop(index) {
    $elements.eq(index).fadeIn(1000, function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $self.fadeOut(1000);
            anim_loop((index + 1) % $elements.length);
        }, 3000);
    }); }

anim_loop(0); // start with the first element
```