# Insert images into a table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm trying to insert jQuery code that contains images to a `<td>` in a table but the images are out of the table bounds. I tried many ways but it didn't work.

**Javscript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
       var $elements = $('#picOne, #picTwo, #picTree, #picFour');

       function anim_loop(index) {
           $elements.eq(index).fadeIn(4000, function() {
               var $self = $(this);
               setTimeout(function() {
               $self.fadeOut(4000);
               anim_loop((index + 1) % $elements.length);
               }, 6000);
           });
        }
        anim_loop(0); // start with the first element

    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<table align="center" width="975" border="1">

<tr>
<td>
<div id="picOne"><img src="pic1.jpg" /></div>
<div id="picTwo"><img src="pic1b.jpg" /></div>
<div id="picTree"><img src="2b.jpg" /></div>
<div id="picFour"><img src="2.jpg" /></div>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: It works here http://jsfiddle.net/u3zPT/, http://jsfiddle.net/seBwg/

Comment: what does `out of the table bounds` mean? do you have any css that hides images to start? Not clear at all what problem is. Create a demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: but as you see here  jsfiddle.net/u3zPT, i want that the numbers be in the same position - in the example number 2 locate under number 1 for 1 sec. what i mean is that when number 1 start the fadeout, number 2 start the fadein. if you dont understand here is my last question and the explain - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537522/how-to-repeat-a-function-call-in-jquery

Comment: other demo @undefined posted does what you want

Comment: no its not, its doesnt do the animation that i want it to. i meant that when pic1 starting the fadeout, pic2 starting the fadein(at the same time), in the second demo its first finish pic1 fadeout, and only after that pic2 start the fade in. i want it to be at the same time(like, pic2 will be "on" pic1).